# Centralizer of diagonal matrices in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-groups

Let $D$ be the subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ containing all the diagonal matrices (of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$). I want to find the centralizer of $D$ in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, namely $C_{SL_n(\mathbb{R})}(D) = \{s \in SL_n(\mathbb{R})| sd = ds \hspace{2.5mm} \forall d \in D \}$. My guess is that it is $D$ itself, since only diagonal matrices commute with all diagonal matrices. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are missing a proof, but the claim is true.

Comment: Any hints for a proof?

Comment: Hint: If vectors $e_i$ form an eigenbasis of $A$, how do you find an eigenbasis of $BAB^{-1}$? Now, what if $ABB^{-1}=A$?

Comment: shouldn't that be $BAB^{-1} = A$ ?

Comment: You can prove by direct calculation of $sd$ and $ds$ that the centralizer of the matrix with $1,2,3,\cdots,n$ on the diagonal is already $D$.

Comment: @ghthorpe: Yes, $BAB^{-1}=A$.